# Reading and manipulating big file in linux efficiently

Tags: linux, file

I've two files

File 1:

```
030055 a
033366 b
```

File 2:

```
03005515077 x||03215549849 y||03336678899 z||03005577733 xx||03005583838 yy
```

A Shell script is required that reads File 1 line by line (030055 a), separates the number value (030055), find it in File 2. If found, replace the character value with 'a' from '030055 a'.

Example:
First record of File1: 030055 a
Compare this with File 2 and the records where this number pattern matches are following

03005515077 x and 03005577733 xx and 03005583838 yy

Just replace x, xx and yy with a  so that it will become

03005515077 a and 03005577733 a and 03005583838 a

Comment: Sorry but we don't do your work for you. What have you tried?

Comment: Did you consider using `awk` and/or `sed` ?

Comment: tried using awk but the sequential line reading takes takes a lot of time

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines (untested);

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
    COL1 = `cat $line | awk '{print $1}'`
    COL2 = `cat $line | awk '{print $2}'`
    sed "s/(${COL1}[0-9]+)[^||]*||/\1 ${COL2}||/g" file_2 > file_2.out
    mv file_2.out file_2
done < "file_1"
```

Comment: `COL1` and `COL2` won't be expanded inside those single quotes. Also, senseless use of `cat`, and `file_2` will get destroyed by the redirection before `sed` ever sees the contents - save to `file_2.out` and rename if necessary. Otherwise, the general idea is right-ish.

Comment: @twalberg you're absolutely right, i just typed that out quite quickly. the redirection is tricky, as it needs to use the same result file per iteration, to result in all the updates. i would suggest building it with `>>` but unmatched results would not be copied across.

Comment: ignore me, its been a long day and most of what i say there is wrong. i had a stab, and will leave it here to be deleted when a more correct answer arrived.

Comment: edited the code to show what I meant about saving to a different file and then renaming...

Comment: @twalberg it occurred to me last night, why don't we just use the `-i` inline/in-place option for `sed`?

Comment: That would certainly work, as well, but I personally avoid it, especially during testing/development of a script, unless I also make provisions to backup the file beforehand.